# Bind parent component using dynamic component feature

Tags: vuejs3

How to bind ComponentType3.vue using `<component v-bind:is="..."></component>` element?

```
ComponentType3.vue
<script>

    import ComponentType1 from './ComponentType1.vue';
    import ComponentType2 from './ComponentType2.vue';

    export default {
        props: ['initModel'],
        data() {
            return {
                model: this.initModel
            }
        }
        components: {
            ComponentType1,
            ComponentType2
        },
        methods: {
            getComponentName(type) {
                return 'Component' + type;
            }
        }
    }

</script>

<template>
        <component v-bind:is="getComponentName(model['Type'])"
        </component>
</template>
```

Sometimes `getComponentName` can return `ComponentType3.vue` but vue does not work as expected because I am getting plain html like `<componenttype3></componenttype3>`. I tried import of `ComponentType3.vue` but it causes circular references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [official docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#recursive-components), recursive component should not be imported, and can be used straight up.

Seems like you need to have a name set for a component to be able to use it recursively. I did setup working [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-heqyqt?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FComp2.vue) that recursively renders itself with certain depth. Make sure your code guarantees that there is finite depth

Comment: I opened your example and see the same problem I have. In App.vue I removed `<Comp2 :root-item="true" />` for simplicity. So I have only `<Comp1 />
    <Comp2 :root-item="false" />` inside App.vue. Now lets inspect Comp 2 component using browser tools. You will see that Comp 2 has a child `<comp2></comp2>`. I don't now why, but child is not resolved the way it should be.

Comment: Apologies, didn't test it through. Changed my sample that renders itself until certain depth. Setting a component name did the trick. Updated answer for future reference

Comment: Wow, it really works! Thank you! I did not knew about this feature, but it solves this situation.

Comment: [Docs](https://vuejs.org/api/options-misc.html#name) for  more details on `name` property